# Does the Z3 theorem prover have a specification for its grammar?

Tags: z3

I'm currently trying to find the BNF specification for Z3 to learn how Z3 constructs its ASTs. For reference, Python has a specification for its ASTs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html.

I looked in the project's repository (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), but I couldn't find the specification there. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: See Appendix B of https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this and found a [repo](https://github.com/julianthome/smtlibv2-grammar) which has an ANTLR v4 grammar for SMTlib v2.
Z3 input language is an extension of SMTlib's grammar, so it should be possible to add the missing grammar rules.

Answer (score 0):

Z3 uses the SMT2 input language, which is defined in the [SMT-LIB Standard](https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/language.shtml). There is no BNF for the ASTs the Z3 keeps internally.